# Simplify a piece of php code, too many repetitions

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

Cant really figure out how to simplify this. What i want is to get contents of these few pages and display them on my site. Is the right way just to repeat the file_get_contents for every page i want or can i do this in another way (maybe all the web sites in one file_get_contents function ?). Also, the rest of the code just repeats its self. I this the whole code just slows down my web site a lot. If somebody is willing to lend a hand :) in this, thank you so much.

```
<?php
//Obtain Quote Info - This collects the Microsoft Stock Info
  $quote10 = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NYSE:GLD');
  $quote9 = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXEURO:PX1');
  $quote8 = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXDJSTOXX:SX5E');
  $quote7 = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXFTSE:UKX');
  $quote4 = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXNIKKEI:NI225');
  $quote5 = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=SHA:000001');
  $quote4 = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXDJX:.DJI');
  $quote3 = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXNASDAQ:.IXIC');
  $quote2 = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXSP:.INX');
  $quote = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:GOOG');
  $quote1 = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:YHOO');

  //Remove CR's from ouput - make it one line
  $json = str_replace("\n", "", $quote);
  $json1 = str_replace("\n", "", $quote1);
  $json2 = str_replace("\n", "", $quote2);
  $json3 = str_replace("\n", "", $quote3);
  $json4 = str_replace("\n", "", $quote4);
  $json5 = str_replace("\n", "", $quote5);
  $json6 = str_replace("\n", "", $quote6);
  $json7 = str_replace("\n", "", $quote7);
  $json8 = str_replace("\n", "", $quote8);
  $json9 = str_replace("\n", "", $quote9);
  $json10 = str_replace("\n", "", $quote10);


  //echo $json['45']; 
  //Remove //, [ and ] to build qualified string  
  $data = substr($json, 4, strlen($json) -5);
  $data1 = substr($json1, 4, strlen($json1) -5);
  $data2 = substr($json2, 4, strlen($json2) -5);
  $data3 = substr($json3, 4, strlen($json3) -5);
  $data4 = substr($json4, 4, strlen($json4) -5);
  $data5 = substr($json5, 4, strlen($json5) -5);
  $data6 = substr($json6, 4, strlen($json6) -5);
  $data7 = substr($json7, 4, strlen($json7) -5);
  $data8 = substr($json8, 4, strlen($json8) -5);
  $data9 = substr($json9, 4, strlen($json9) -5);
  $data10 = substr($json10, 4, strlen($json10) -5);

  //decode JSON data
  $json_output = json_decode($data, true);
  $json_output1 = json_decode($data1, true);
  $json_output2 = json_decode($data2, true);
  $json_output3 = json_decode($data3, true);
  $json_output4 = json_decode($data4, true);
  $json_output5 = json_decode($data5, true);
  $json_output6 = json_decode($data6, true);
  $json_output7 = json_decode($data7, true);
  $json_output8 = json_decode($data8, true);
  $json_output9 = json_decode($data9, true);
  $json_output10 = json_decode($data10, true);


  //Un-remark print_r to see all array keys
  //print_r($json_output);

  //Output Stock price array key.
  echo "\n".$json_output['t'],"\n".$json_output['l'],"\n".$json_output['cp'];echo "<br />"; 
  echo "\n".$json_output1['t'],"\n".$json_output1['l'],"\n".$json_output1['cp'];echo "<br />"; 
  echo "\n".$json_output2['t'],"\n".$json_output2['l'],"\n".$json_output2['cp'];echo "<br />"; 
  echo "\n".$json_output3['t'],"\n".$json_output3['l'],"\n".$json_output3['cp'];echo "<br />";
  echo "\n".$json_output4['t'],"\n".$json_output4['l'],"\n".$json_output4['cp'];echo "<br />";
  echo "\n".$json_output5['t'],"\n".$json_output5['l'],"\n".$json_output5['cp'];echo "<br />";
  echo "\n".$json_output6['t'],"\n".$json_output6['l'],"\n".$json_output6['cp'];echo "<br />";
  echo "\n".$json_output7['t'],"\n".$json_output7['l'],"\n".$json_output7['cp'];echo "<br />";
  echo "\n".$json_output8['t'],"\n".$json_output8['l'],"\n".$json_output8['cp'];echo "<br />";
  echo "\n".$json_output9['t'],"\n".$json_output9['l'],"\n".$json_output9['cp'];echo "<br />";
  echo "\n".$json_output10['t'],"\n".$json_output10['l'],"\n".$json_output10['cp'];
```

Comment: Use arrays and `for` loops. However, they will make your code look better but they won't help speed-wise. I think this is about as fast as it can get - the bottleneck is the HTTP requests and you won't get around those.

Answer (score 5):

Just use an array and a for each loop.

```
 $stock_array = array('NYSE:GLD', 'INDEXEURO:PX1', 'INDEXDJSTOXX:SX5E', etc..);

 foreach ($stock_array as $stock) {

 $quote = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q='.$stock);

 $json = str_replace("\n", "", $quote);
 $data = substr($json, 4, strlen($json) -5);
 $json_output = json_decode($data, true);
 echo "\n".$json_output['t'],"\n".$json_output['l'],"\n".$json_output['cp'];echo "<br />"; 

 }
```

Hope this helps,
Phil

Comment: works wonders, definitely more simple and as users said it did not speed up anything. the request is the problem it seems. Will try to figure something out and will post here when a solution arises. thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts:

1) IF the main problem is it slowing down your site, cache the value using Memcached or similar, so you don't have to fire 5000 requests/sec for information that doesn't change.

2) Could you have each user's browser load this asynchronously with javascript so each block loads as it becomes available and therefore allows the navigation, etc. to load immediately?

3) If you really need to do some data massaging of this data coming back from google's api, you could have a separate php page that's like a handle_google_data.php file that your users' browser hits asynchronously with javascript.

4) You might throw some microtime(true) statements throughout your code to see what's taking the longest (I'm fairly positive it will be the api calls).

Good luck!
-Z.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and modify the `$json_var` to get the output that you need. 
`$file_arr` is containing the file paths that you need to call.

```
$output_var = '';
function my_function($file_path)
{
  $quote = file_get_contents($file_path);
  $json = str_replace("\n", "", $quote);
  $data = substr($json, 4, strlen($json) -5);
  $json_output = json_decode($data, true);
  $json_var = "\n".$json_output['t'].",\n".$json_output['l'].",\n".$json_output['cp'].'<br />';
  return $json_var;

}         

    $file_arr = array('0'=>'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NYSE:GLD','1'=>'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXEURO:PX1');

            foreach($file_arr as $k=>$v):
            $output_var .= my_function($v);
            endforeach;

            echo $output_var;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your links in an array like this then run a foreach through them.

```
$quotelinks = array(
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:GOOG',
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:YHOO',
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXSP:.INX',
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXNASDAQ:.IXIC',
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXDJX:.DJI',
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=SHA:000001',
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXNIKKEI:NI225',
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXFTSE:UKX',
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXDJSTOXX:SX5E',
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXEURO:PX1',
  'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NYSE:GLD');


foreach ($quotelinks as $quotelink) {
  $quote = file_get_contents($quotelink);
  $json = str_replace("\n", "", $quote);
  $data = substr($json, 4, strlen($json) -5);
  $json_output = json_decode($data, true);
  echo "\n".$json_output['t'],"\n".$json_output['l'],"\n".$json_output['cp'];echo "<br />"; 
}
```